# What is the ratio of $b$ to $a$

Tags: geometry

> Four distinct points are arranged on a plane so that the segments connecting them have lengths $a$, $a$, $a$, $a$, $2a$, and $b$. What is the ratio of $b$ to $a$?

This question can be solved since we know that the ratio is constant by constructing an equilateral triangle then proceeding. But my question is why is the ratio constant? How do we prove that the ratio is an invariant for any $4$ distinct points?

Comment: if the points are distinct, $b = a \sqrt 3,$ as the edge to the fourth point is a parallel extension of one edge of the equilateral triangle, and is also length $a,$

Comment: @WillJagy So there is only $1$ construction?

Comment: If the four points make a rhombus, it is not possible to get the diagonal as large as $2a$ unless two of the points squeeze into one.

Comment: There is only one "construction" but may be several solutions.

Comment: @Moti What do you mean by solution?

Comment: @user19405892 Actually there is only one solution. Will you approve this one to "compensate" for the effort?:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After additional consideration, the solution to this means that 2a participates in at least two triangles, so three points are on a line.[image]

The result is a right angle triangle and from this b may be easily calculated (left for some USER work:)) and the ratio is $\sqrt{3}$